# where is Header file in the Zone(Model.Header)?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7

How can I find out the address of the files in orchard 
I select the inspect mode in browser link and the click on an item in browser 
so give me this part of the Layout file in vs 
Zone(Model.Header)
Now how can I find out where is the Model.Header in the Sources file ?
generally how can I find the link of the file in orchard ?
Thanks
Great Regards :
Raha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can use the Shape Tracing feature (built-in, just enable it from under Modules) to explore where different pieces of the layout come from.

The header zone's markup specifically comes from a shape method (as the markup of shapes can be defined not just in templates, but also in shape methods) in `Orchard.Core.Shapes.CoreShapes.Zone()`.

Comment: Thanks for answer . if we can't find files how we can add item to them . for example if i want to add slideshow ( Image slides right to left ) to homepage how can I do it . in which file I must add the source code of slideshow to have it's view in homepage ?

Comment: Shape Tracing also lets you create templates from under Alternates. From this you can create templates that will only be used e.g. on the home page. Also please mark my answer as an answer if it was helpful.

Comment: really thanks for you're answer . but i've worked with wordpress . now I'm new in orchard . so please tell me more about the file in orchard . for example which file is homepage to add and customize it . shape tracing is actived now . the orchard theme is default . which is homepage file to add my slidshow to it ? please tell me it ?

Comment: This is a bigger topic then to explain in a comment but see the "Creating Themes" topics in the docs: http://docs.orchardproject.net/ For styling the home page specifically see this: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates#URLandWidgetAlternates BTW the core of the Orchard layout is a template called Layout(.cshtml). There are several of this in the solution and you can have one in your own theme to override the default one.

Comment: "Generally you can use the Shape Tracing feature (built-in, just enable it from under Modules)"... Can you be more specific on where to find this in Orchard Core Admin? thx

Comment: This is about Orchard 1.x that has a component named Orchard.Core... Unfortunately, Orchard Core doesn't have Shape Tracing.